# Resolving 'unknown revision or path' error when resetting commit in CodeCommit

Tags: github

We are two developers, working in the same branch, i'm pushed a commit,but it delete the last commit, i wanna reset to the commit deleted using code commit, but this error message displayed

fatal: ambiguous argument 'codeCommit': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'